# Calling Controller Function in Ajax

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, asp.net, ajax

I want to call this yellow colored Controller function with ajax ([Image of my project](http://i019.radikal.ru/1401/73/032d01449217.jpg)). 
and this is my JavaScript function in View:

```
function notificationDivPressed(element,x,user,numberOfUsers) {  

    jQuery(document).ready(function ($) {

        $.ajax({
            url: 'MvcApplication3/Controllers/NotificationController/ChangeReadStatus',
            type: "POST",
            cache: false,
            data: { arg: x },
            success: function (data) {

                }
            }
        });
    });   
}
```

when I write url like that (url: 'MvcApplication3/Controllers/NotificationController/ChangeReadStatus') it doesn't work. What should I change to get a desired result?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you saw your URL is wrong (because you're just using a mix of project paths and class name instead of proper URL that MVC framework will rewrite and route to right methods).

Change it with:

```
url: '@Url.Action("ChangeReadStatus", "Notification")'
```

Answer (score 0):

Change to

```
url: '/Notification/ChangeReadStatus'
```

Comment: Please do him a favor and don't hard-code action method URLs!

Comment: Adriano, got it. Thought it might be easier for him to understand for a beginner. But you are right.